# Setting CacheDirectory in download-maven-plugin

Tags: maven

While using download-maven-plugin I am trying to set a different cacheDirectory for it  in my local repo. But when I set it to ${local-repo} in my pom.xml, it creates a new folder called ${local-repo} in my current project and places cache there while I want it to go to ~/.m2/repository/myFolder.

Comment: Why do you need this plugin? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @khmarbaise I am trying to download some files from the server which are then used in my build script. Do you know other good plugin or method to do the same?